# English equivalent of "garam" (warming) food?

Tags: expressions, translation, food

I want to know how we say in English when we want to say that almonds or other dry fruits are "hot" for our body. I am an Indian, and in India, we use the word *garam* which literally means *hot* in English. I want to know how native speakers of English say this in English.

*Garam* foods are not necessarily hot to touch, but produce heat in the body. In excess they may be harmful or indigestible. For instance, a consumer might get pimples from eating too much of 'garam food' -for example- dry fruit.

The effects of almonds is opposite that of lemonade, which is *thandaa* in  nature i.e. 'cold' in English when it's literally translated from Hindi. I googled it but found nothing, so I hope that I'll get my answer here.

Comment: "The effect of almonds is opposite to the effect of lemonade" - what does it mean? What is the effect of lemonade?

Comment: What do you mean by "hot for our body"? When describing foods in English, "hot" can mean "spicy" or it can mean "at a high temperature". Almonds and dried fruit aren't either of those things, so I take it you mean something else, but I don't know what. (BTW: "hot for her body" is an idiom meaning "finds her sexually desirable". I don't think that's what you mean either.)

Comment: @Kreiri I mean to say that lemonade is cold in opposition to almonds, which are hot. The words 'hot' and 'cold' are literally translated from Indian language, but I want to know how exactly native speakers of English say.

Comment: But, unless they're freshly roasted, almonds are not "hot"... they're room temperature at best.

Comment: We can't tell you the English equivalent, because we have no idea what you mean. Don't translate the words directly, *describe the effect*.

Comment: By eating too much almonds, perhaps our body temperature rises or something like that. I mean the almonds in access are somehow harmful or they don't digest. The consumer gets pimples on his skin by eating too much dry fruits.

Comment: I've never heard any of that... Is that scientifically supported information?

Comment: I think there is a similar concept in Chinese medicine, where food can be Yin or Yang, depending on which kind of food it is. I tried Wikipedia and found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_food_therapy): "Food items are classified as "heating" (*re* 熱; "hot") or "cooling" (*liang* 涼; "cool")."

Comment: This dichotomy does not exist in American understanding of foods.  It is simply not translatable.  If you asked an American the difference between lemonade and almonds, they would point out liquid solid, but the _"garam"/"non-garam"_  spectrum would need detailed explanation.  ( <5% of the population who might sort of understand it from _Yin/yang_ as suggested by @DamkerngT.)  Once you explain the idea, you would probably find strong disagreement, because in general almonds are thought of as extremely healthy, and I (at least) have never heard any urban legends about dry fruit causing pimples.

Comment: As a BrE native I was brought up on curry. At a young age I learnt to distinguish garam masala from other spices. Garam masala is hot, bringing fire to the palate, whereas paprika or cumin are more spicy. The difference between hot and spicy ia difficult to explain linguistically, but fairly easy to differentiate on the tongue!

Comment: It should be noted that even if this concept exists in a language, it still may not mean what you think it means. Different cultures have different definitions of "garam" and hence different languages will have different things defined as hot/cold. Take for example Malay where lamb/goat meat is considered hot but Arabic where lamb/goat meat is considered cold. The belief is such that people actually experience physiological symptoms such as sweating or cramps. Both can't be right but paradoxically both are. Arabic speakers really feel cool when eating lamb and Malays feel the opposite.

Comment: Fun fact: "garam" and "warm" are cognates, that is, they are related words (both descended from Proto-Indo-European *ghwermos*). N.B. in my native culture (Iranian) we have the exact same concept with "garm" (warm) and "sard" (cold) foods.

Comment: @DamkerngT. More commonly, the ‘hot’ and ‘cold’ foodstuffs in Chinese are referred to as 上火 _shàng huǒ_ ‘raising fire’ and 降火 _jiàng huǒ_ ‘lowering/reducing fire’, respectively. _Fire_ is here the perceived effect of the ‘hot’ foodstuffs on the body; or rather, it’s the term for an excessive level of ‘heat’ in the body. Body ‘heat’ should be balanced, which is why too high levels of it can be countered by eating ‘fire-reducing’ foods and too low levels of it can be countered by eating ‘fire-raising’ foods.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Western cuisine does not have a direct equivalent to *garam*, as there is no philosophical division of foods as there is in Ayurvedic or traditional Chinese medicine.

When the concept is translated, *garam* is generally translated as *warming*, and the opposite as *cooling*. If you are trying to preserve the original context and refer to Eastern concepts of warming and cooling foods, you will need to explain this, as there is simply no Western equivalent. I doubt any Westerner would guess that dill and wild rice are traditionally considered warming while cilantro and chicken eggs are considered cooling.

It is particularly important because all cuisines *do* understand that certain foods or flavors will be ***warming*** or ***cooling***, but in English these terms are used much more restrictively, to refer to their literal effect on our palate or body temperature (or our perception of them). I don't think anyone would dispute that chili powder mixed into hot chocolate is warming, but no Westerner would automatically associate overconsumption with indigestion or unhealthy skin because it is warming.

In general usage, most foods would be considered neutral, and those classified as warming or cooling may differ considerably from Indian or Chinese tradition. Nuts and lemonade are neither, except when they are literally hot or cold (e.g. freshly roasted nuts or ice-chilled lemonade).

(Note also that *lemonade* means different things in different places. In Britain it is a fizzy drink, like a light Sprite or 7-Up without the lime. In North America it is uncarbonated and similar to what Britons would call a *lemon squash*, and a lemon squash can be served hot or cold).

Comment: I have never heard of a Lemon Squash before, nor have I ever heard of hot lemonade.  So yes, lemonade would be similar to a Lemon Squash for North Americans, but asking if a North American has hot lemonade would get some very confused glances indeed.

Comment: @Zibbobz Right, lemonade in the American sense is never served hot, in the US or Canada. But a drink prepared in the same way with the same ingredients, elsewhere called a *squash*, [*can* be served hot](http://www.walesonline.co.uk/news/wales-news/scientists-tell-what-already-know-2133797). Sorry if I was not clear. There is no direct American equivalent for [what the British call lemonade](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40791/).

Comment: Americans call it *hot lemonade.* It is not as common, or commonly known of, as (cold) lemonade, but a google search shows a good number of references to it, and a COCA search shows it used in a *Washington Post* article.

Comment: As someone who's had both lemonade and lemon squash... they are **not** the same thing.

Comment: AmE here:  I don't know what a _lemon squash_ is - never heard of it.   _Lemonade_ in the States is lemon juice, water and  just enough sugar to take the edge off, while still being a bit tart.  _Hot lemonade_ is what you order when you go out with friends and they order beers, but you are sick and/or pregnant, and you don't want peppermint tea.  If I ordered it, I would expect to get exactly the same lemonade as I described earlier, but microwaved for a minute.

Comment: "but no Westerner would automatically associate overconsumption with indigestion or unhealthy skin because it is warming." However, people often do associate certain types of food (chocolate and fried foods often top the list of foods blamed for acne) with unhealthy skin for various other reasons.

Comment: "...their literal effect on our palate or **body temperature**" - Although, rather confusingly, the OP does state that "Garam foods ... are "warming" to the body, **raising the body temperature**." ... maybe not literally?!

Comment: @w3d I think one case is food that is literally hot (high temperature), vs food that the body works harder to digest and causes more waste energy.

Comment: This answer is good but not precisely addressing the concern. The question is actually asking for an Ayurvedic term. There's no english term for that. I've answered with the closest term possible. however it's not a term defined in any dictionary but we professionals have coined it. I'm a professional Ayurveda physician.

Comment: Wait, American lemonade isn't fizzy? This explains a lot.

Comment: So, you say eggs are "cooling", and Maulik V, the self-described "Ayurvedic physician", says they are garam/"heaty".  Which is correct? Are chicken eggs an exceptional kind of eggs?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Eggs are cooling in Chinese terms—perhaps that’s where the confusion arises.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock thanks for not using *'self-proclaimed'* lol. In modern science, there's **no** explanation for that and I already said that. But those who are *not* habituated eating eggs daily (like me), if eat 3 eggs a day (with yolk) for a week for whatsoever reason, they're likely to develop stomatitis or such signs. Imagine Brian coming to India and having North Indian spicy food with pickles; within a week, your bowels will give up! :) that's body heat. Now don't ask what 'heat' has to do with peristalsis movement! That's again Ayurveda lol

Answer (score 20):

This is my take; I'm an *Ayurvedic* physician!

Literally, गरम (pronounced - ga ra m) in Hindi is 'hot' in English - loud and clear.

But, in India, what we mean by गरम is *producing body heat* after the digestion. In Ayurveda, eggs, eggplant, chili, black pepper, etc. are considered as गरम, because the heat is **actually** produced when they are metabolized by our digestive system. The Ayurvedic term for that is 'विपाक' (pronounced -vee paa k). Precisely, विपाक denotes very vast meaning which
explain to the digestion, assimilation, metabolism, absorption and
bio-transformation up to the cellular level of ingested drug or food.

It is interesting to know that Ayurveda classifies the effects of drug/food according to its 'end' effects and not the ephemeral effects. For instance, we all call a 'cold drink', but is it really cold? **NO**. The end effects of such drink, at a cellular level, according to the holistic science of Ayurveda, is acidic. In this way, Ayurveda may consider today's cold drinks as 'heaty drinks'.

The विपाक also has a time factor. Depending upon the state of the food/drug, the विपाक changes. This means the same food which is 'cool' **becomes** 'heaty' depending upon the 'time factor'. The best example I can think of is mango. A raw mango, according to Ayurveda, is 'heaty'. But then, a fully ripened mango is 'cooling' and nourishing.

Now, when we (Indians) **don't find** any suitable word, we take *some* liberty and make our own word for that. Especially in a folk medicine practice, it's widely done. I, myself, have done it to make foreigners understand. Though it looks *silly*, but ultimately, it conveys the meaning. For internal purposes, we set the **closest** term for it. And it's always 'safe' to say, '**We call** it as...[newly coined term]'.

And, the term for such food is ***heaty***. It's not an English word yet; but it's steadily getting accepted by many.

Some of the examples are here:

> What do “heaty” and “cooling” in TCM really mean? - [Men's Health](http://www.menshealth.com.sg/health/what-do-%E2%80%9Cheaty%E2%80%9D-and-%E2%80%9Ccooling%E2%80%9D-tcm-really-mean), a reputed magazine
>   The list of 'heaty' foods - [A Chinese website on Traditional Herbs](http://www.rxt.com.sg/tcm-tips-heaty-cooling-food.php)
>   What are heaty and cooling foods - [Some blog](http://www.benefits-of-honey.com/heaty.html)

If you google ['heaty foods' in Google News,](https://www.google.com/search?q=heaty%20foods&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=heaty%20foods&tbm=nws) you find many magazines and dailies are accepting this term. Maybe, some day, we'll have a better word for this. Till then, there's no harm in using it. If a native speaker asks, you may simply explain that...

> heaty food - *the food that produced body heat after being digested* (self-made definition)

Comment: +1 for the links showing that 'heaty' is gaining traction.

Comment: This answer is very good. I took liberties to fix some typos and punctuation marks. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Just curious: are there reliable scientific studies that demonstrate the heating & cooling effects ascribed to various foods by Ayurvedic tradition, and if so, have they documented which foods are most and least "heaty", or most and least "cooling"?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock unfortunately no scientific evidences for heaty/cooling foods. As an Ayurvedic physician, I can get you the list (that's totally out of ELL though...haha). If modern scientists were into it, they'd have had already come up with a better term for 'heaty food'! What say? :)

Answer (score 15):

**Garam** is simply not translatable to American English.

This dichotomy does not exist in American understanding of foods. If you asked an American the difference between lemonade and almonds, they would say one is liquid and the other solid, but the *"garam"/"non-garam"* spectrum would need detailed explanation. (Some very small percentage of the population might sort of understand it from *yin/yang* as suggested by @DamkerngT.)

If you refer to a food as "hot," we would think you mean it is either high temperature, like a cup of boiling water, or very spicy. Cold food  low temperature like ice-cream.

Once you explain the idea, you would probably find strong skepticism, because in general almonds are thought of as healthy, and I (at least) have never heard any urban legends about dry fruit causing pimples.

---

Related Example:

Do you have the expression *"finger food"* in India?  In the U.S., there are some foods for which it is socially acceptable to eat without using a utensil - we can touch them directly with our fingers, even in a nice restaurant.  There isn't a firm list I can give you - it would be slightly different for different communities, but it is things like bread and butter, some pizzas, fruit slices, potato chips.  In some parts of the country, fried chicken is finger food.  In others it is not.  Sauces are never finger food unless they are being used as dip for something that is finger food like carrot sticks or tortilla chips.  Hardboiled eggs are finger food unless they are cut into more than two pieces.  Fried eggs are *not* finger food.

There are many places in the world where a literal translation of the word *finger* and the word *food* would fall very short of conveying the idea, and even when the idea was explained, people would find it peculiar.  So it is with *garam* for us.

Comment: it's worth noting that none of this is specific to american english. it applies to all western english.

Comment: "in general almonds are thought of as healthy" AIUI there's something of a movement to consider almonds and other nuts unhealthy unless "activated" (sprouted)

Comment: Dry fruit contains some oil (often added to preserve it) and some sugar, both of which can cause pimples, perhaps?

Comment: "Garam is simply not translatable. This dichotomy does not exist in American understanding of foods." Has it occurred to you that the dichotomy might exist in some other variety of English? For example, Indian English? You write as if English simply doesn't exist outside the USA.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Wow - Of course I am aware that the dichotomy may exist elsewhere. That's why I mentioned three times in my answer that I was referring to U.S. culture and American English.  The original poster said that in India, they use the word "Garam" itself, so I assumed he didn't need me to tell him that.   I added a fourth reference to the U.S. in the first line, to make it even more clear that I am answering with regards to that which I know about.

Answer (score 11):

As others have said, the concept simply does not exist in English/American culture.  The only people who would have even the foggiest idea of what you're talking about are those who have some acquaintance Indian cooking or culture, and if we discuss the concept in English, we borrow the Indian words.

Comment: Good point on the borrowing.  If the idea caught on to the point of being commonly understood, we would eventually consider "garam" to be an English word.

Comment: @Adam: Yes, in much the same way as English has borrowed e.g. karma and guru.

Comment: exactly.... that's what and why I answered it! :) In fact, this is a typical problem we had when I finished my studies and started practicing!

Answer (score 0):

Aggravating.

"Garam" in this context does not really mean the food is hot or spicy. It refers to food that is aggravating to our system. Almonds are hard to digest so it overworks our digestive system. The use of the word "Garam" is not wrong because the stomach needs to heat up to sufficient temperature to digest the food which in case of "Garam" foods is higher than other foods. An overworked and overheated system produces more toxins than the body can handle. Eating too many almonds or eggs in summer time may give you pimples or ulcers. This is the body's way of disposing off those toxins. Body builders are well aware of this problem. To counter these effects drink lots of water. Almonds can be soaked in water over night to make them easier on the stomach.

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, this does not actually answer the question of how to say this in English.

Comment: @Catija I think the suggestion is that _Garam_ foods might be called _aggravating_ foods in English to get a closer translation than "warming". I couldn't say for certain whether this is a good translation or not, but I do think it attempts to answer the question.

Comment: @ColleenV Oh... then it needs some serious rewording to make that more clear.  Either way, "aggravating" would not make anyone think of the concept because, as the other answers have stated, there is no concept of this in English.

Comment: @Catija I'm not sure there's no equivalent in English . Certainly the most precise word would be Garam, but aggravating might capture the concept well enough to communicate it to English speakers with a different cultural background.

Comment: @ColleenV: I don't think it works as a direct translation.  Maybe in the context of someone trying to  explain ayurvedic concepts, but there are so many other ways that foods can be aggravating - steak or corn that gets stuck in your teeth, things that drip when you're trying to eat them...

Comment: @Catija _garam_ in general context translates to _hot_. but in reference to food it means aggravating. Since _garam_ in this meaning will only be used in reference to food _aggravating_ is applicable. If i say "garam" it will mean hot and if i say  "this food is garam" it will mean the food is aggravating.

Comment: "Aggravating" may be a good translation, I'm not familiar enough with the concept of *garam* to say. But the questioner is more specifically asking what native English speakers use, and AFAIK (being British) it isn't generally used here. Tell most native English that eating almonds raises their body temperature, they might not even believe you, and if they did the term they'd use for it is "increasing body temperature". They wouldn't call them "aggravating" because they're unaware of any of these unhealthy effects.

Comment: You cite no examples and don't show your use in even an example sentence of your own. That's what I mean by context.

Comment: @SteveJessop I think you're confusing language with culture. I know many "native English speakers" whose cultural backgrounds aren't Western. I think that you can be a native speaker of British or American English and still be familiar with the concept of garam foods. Whether such folks use a word other than Garam to describe the concept, I don't know, but I wouldn't presume that such a translation doesn't exist because I don't personally know it. Not all native English speakers have the same vocabulary ;)

Comment: @ColleenV: excellent, would you mind ending the speculation by asking them what word they use for the concept of *garam* when speaking English! I agree there's a conflation of language with culture, but in common with several others here I'm assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that the questioner is asking for a word generally intelligible internationally to a wide range of English-speakers. Therefore culture is relevant. Maybe the questioner doesn't care about that, though, and would be happy with a word unintelligible to Americans and whatnot.

Comment: @ParitoshBhatia: true, it was Gurpreet who said it increased body temperature, you said it increases stomach temperature. Anyway, substitute any of the symptoms you list in place of "increases body temperature" in my first comment, and it still more or less applies. I repeat, I'm not saying the word "aggravate" is inapplicable, or that it can't be used to describe this combination of symptoms. I'm saying that's not what it would be understood to designate, we'd all be thinking "aggravate in what way?". We might think you mean "causes stomach pain" or something.

Comment: ... so for example, I think most of the English-speaking world would agree, if pressed, that strychnine is "aggravating", but does poisoning really correspond with the concept of garam? An epic quantity of almonds could cause hydrogen cyanide poisoning, as it happens, but I suspect that's not relevant since cyanide isn't dealt with by the stomach, it's processed by the liver.

Comment: Not to object to the word "aggravating", but I'm not sure if it's the right word. A five-minute reading on Ayurveda (อายุรเวท) gave me this idea: human bodies are governed by three kinds of energy (Tri Dosha; ตรีโทษ): Vata (วาตะ ~ air), Pitta (ปิตตะ ~ fire), and Kapha (กผะ ~ earth+water). It seems like different kinds of foods will aggravate different kinds of energies. And I guess that "garam" food will specifically aggravate Pitta (fire).

Comment: For example, I found people saying this: *With this in mind, I typically advise people to stay away from almonds as the molds themselves aggravate pitta.* and this: *A pitta dominant person can NOT have spinach. Spinach is incredibly heating and drying which aggravates people of a pitta dosha.*

Comment: @Paritosh Bhatia: That's sort of my point.  "Common sense" doesn't apply here, because Western European culture in general (not just American/British) just does not have the necessary background concepts.  It'd be like trying to explain Jewish dietary laws to Indians.

Comment: _Aggravating_ is a bad translation word by itself, but I wonder if you could say "aggravating to the digestive system." In a case like this, it might be better to translate into a short phrase rather than a single word.

Comment: A north american would not accept these pre-scientific concepts of warming/cooling (or, for that matter, "toxins" from "overheating").  We would, of course, accept that almonds, being nuts, have significant fat, protein and fiber, and are thus not as easy to digest in large quantities as other foods.  Mostly, the West doesn't give much credence to pre-modern  ("classical") concepts like this (or earth/air/fire/water).

Answer (score 0):

I think we say 'fatty foods' - this would include lamb, butter, milk, sugary things, nuts. Is that closer to what you mean? I think the confusion is that english uses hot to mean spicy or hot (heat). We would not think of almonds as hot so yours is a different usage.

I thought almonds quite healthy together with walnuts. Peanuts , which actually are a legume , are 'fatty'.

Perhaps you mean just 'difficult to digest' in which case we sometimes say 'heavy' as in you don't eat a 'heavy meal' late at night.

Answer (score -2):

The process is called 'Thermogenesis' in English. So, not sure, what the food may be called relatively. I guess a food with 'Garam taaseer' which can literally be translated as 'hot effect/influence' may be called a 'thermogenetic food'.
I'm from Pakistan basically.
I hope this solves everything.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners and thanks for answering. Since this is your first posting I'm reviewing it in order to be helpful. Your answer has already been voted down. In order to avoid this I would suggest not guessing, but only answer when you're sure that you're correct and you can back up your answer with citations or examples. In addition, the word 'thermogenesis' refers to the process of heat production, which happens through digestion. But the questioner is looking for a term for food that might not be good for digestion. You can edit your answer if you want to improve it.

Answer (score -4):

I am sorry to throw "cold" water on this "hot" topic, but the Hindi word garam simply means "hot, warm". In English too we talk about "hot" foods, like hot peppers, which are not actually hot, but simply spicy, body-warming.

You might be interested to know that Hindi garam गरम is actually a borrowing from Persian garm, which in turn is cognate with Sanskrit घर्म gharma "heat".

Comment: Simply not true.  'Hot' meaning an effect like that of the capsaicin in chili peppers is an entirely different concept from the garam 'hot' concept in Ayurveda.  See the good answer by Maulik V above, or use Google.

Comment: @jamesqf Are you contesting that the Hindi word garam means "hot"?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the concept of garam in Ayurveda has absolutely nothing to do with anything westerners would think of as heat.  It's like the example someone used above, of a "hot chick".  Now the 'chick' is actually a young human female, not a newly-hatched bird, and almost certainly has the same body temperature as non-hot females, so a literal translation without cultural context makes zero sense.