# The meaning of "Constipating"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> The Henna tree has two special qualities: decomposing due to its warm watery essence, and **constipating** due to the cold earthly essence it contains.
>
> [Healing with The Medicine of The Prophets](https://books.google.com/books?id=prBB0SHtoWYC&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=%22decomposing+due+to+its+warm+watery+essence,+and+constipating%22&source=bl&ots=F__S3C_m9f&sig=ACfU3U247YiaK7E-DrHwWoLditwl5nmlVQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdnsvx1vrvAhWHwAIHHSQmC8AQ6AEwBXoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=%22decomposing%20due%20to%20its%20warm%20watery%20essence%2C%20and%20constipating%22&f=false)

I don't understand the meaning of "constipating here".

There are only two definitions of 'constipate' in Merriam-Webster:

> Definition of **constipate**
> transitive verb
>
> 1: to cause constipation in
> 2: to make immobile, inactive, or dull : STULTIFY
> so much clutter … will tend to constipate the novel's working order 
> — *The Times Literary Supplement (London)*

I think both definitions aren't suitable for this context, but I'm not very sure. The word "decomposing" is also weird here. I don't think a tree decomposes just because of its essence.

Comment: In a medical context, 'constipating' is the opposite of 'laxative'.

Comment: Your mystic-medicine book was written, and probably translated, by non-native speakers.

Comment: Related question: [English equivalent of “garam” (warming) food?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/53200/9161) There may be cultural meaning to the special qualities that are not fully captured by the dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Meaning 1.  Causing constipation.  The Henna tree contains a "cold earthy essence".  This will cause your poo to go hard and prevent diarrhoea (according to the book).

But it also "decomposes".  It helps food to break down in your stomach.

You will find a lot of traditional herbal medicine is about digestion and poo.